# MySQL sum two tables fields and UPDATE

Tags: mysql, sql, sum, database-table

Im trying how to sum id by id two tables and update the one :

STOCKA

```
---------
|P | U |
|-------|
| 1 | 1 |
| 2 | 0 |
| 3 | 3 |
---------
```

STOCKB

```
--------- 
|P | U |
|-------|
| 1 | -3 |
| 2 | -2 |
| 3 | -1 |
---------
```

Results I want :

STOCKA

```
--------
|P | U |
|--------|
| 1 | -2 |
| 2 | -2 |
| 3 | 2 |
---------
```

My query  :

```
UPDATE STOCKA,STOCKB
SET STOCKA.U =  STOCKA.U - ABS(STOCKB.U)
WHERE
STOCKA.P = STOCKB.P
```

Comment: What is the problem with your query?

Comment: in my query the results values are wrong, i use the answer of hjpotter92. 
Thanks :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use JOIN instead of trying to pass two tables in an UPDATE statement:

```
UPDATE STOCKA a
JOIN STOCKB b
    ON a.P = b.P
SET a.U =  a.U - ABS(b.U)
```

Comment: Thanks! for modify my post and the correct answer. 
This is great ! :D

Answer (score 0):

The query in your question should work, if there is only one row in the "b" table for each `P`.  If there can be more than one row, then aggregate first and then join:

```
UPDATE STOCKA a join
       (select P, sum(abs(u)) as bu
        from STOCKB
        group by P
       ) b
       on a.P = b.P
    SET a.U =  a.U - b.bu;
```